# iOS 17 Video Upload Issue: .jpeg Format Error

Tags: javascript, iphone, video, ios17

Video Format Issue on iOS 17 After Editing with Apps like Soda, Beauty Cam, Meitu, Snow - JavaScript Check Returns .jpeg Format

I am facing an issue with the video format when users use editing apps such as Soda, Beauty Cam, Meitu, Snow on iOS 17 and then upload the video to our website. Customer feedback indicates their videos are encountering errors, and upon investigation, I found that the file extension of the videos is being mistakenly identified as .jpeg.

After a few days of investigation, I observed that the problem only occurs on devices running iOS 17 and with videos edited through the mentioned apps. I tried using a JavaScript code snippet to check the file type, and immediately upon upload, the video format was determined as .jpeg. This issue is specific to iOS 17, with no similar problems observed on iOS 16 and earlier versions.

This is a video file recorded using the Snow app on iOS 17, and the exported file has the .jpeg format right from the start. Interestingly, this error does not occur consistently, and sometimes the exported video is in the .mp4 format (i.e., the correct format). After transferring these files to my computer, they automatically become .mp4 files.[image]

I am trying to find an alternative solution to check whether a file is a video, besides using the file type check. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide information on this issue?

Comment: Your question needs more useful details (including a link to a testable video file that gives a problem)... **(1)** Looking in the storage folder, do these files show as having an .mp4 or .jpeg extension? **(2)** _" I tried using a JavaScript code snippet to check the file type, and immediately upon upload, the video format was determined as .jpeg"_ Show an example of such code snippet. Not clear how an mp4 extension is reported as jpeg extension... **(3)** The best solution would be to just check the bytes of the uploaded file. It's not obvious what those apps are doing to the file header.

Comment: PS: You are using Javascript's File API, right? So what happens when you check `file.name` on a uploaded video file, I mean is the last 4 characters showing as `.mp4` or not?

Comment: The original video file itself, created from the apps, has the .jpeg extension. I have provided an image of the file after recording the video.

Comment: It looks like you need to check the inside of the file. Not sure how your _"..Upon upload, the video format was determined as .jpeg"_ How was this determined by your JS code? Does your code have something like `myFile = evt.target.files[0];`? If yes then you need to use a **FileReader** on the file. You can first `.slice` the file to get maybe the first 100 bytes then use FileReader to either check as binary values or check as text. An easy first test is to read 100 bytes as text (into a String). Check if the 100 character string has `ftyp` in there. If yes, then such file is either MP4 or MOV

Comment: PS Can you **show a testable code** that allows for file selecting and then it also does a console log that would show the extension (for your problem files it should say `.jpeg`)? Then someone can try improve it to check the internal file bytes to determine the content type.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting a solution. I have researched the ftyp code and addressed the issue by checking the file on the backend using Laravel, with the following code:
`$fileContent = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath(), false, null, 4, 4); // Read 4 bytes from offset 4
$expectedFtypBox = '66747970'; // Hex for the 'ftyp' string in mp4, mov, m4v
$isVideo = false;
$hexFromFile = bin2hex($fileContent);

if (strtolower($hexFromFile) === $expectedFtypBox) $isVideo = true;`

Comment: **Excellent**. You should post that as an Answer (and mark it as correct so others know it works). If you do it, I can throw in a useful Javascript version (for those who are maybe using the JS File API, not PHP or Laravel).